# SAML Protocol Response Passthrough ADFS to WIF RP

Tags: saml, adfs, ws-federation, federation

presently we have ADFS 3.0 acting as federation gateway among multiple client IDPs and our web application. So in summary, for client IDPs our ADFS act as Relying Party, while for our in house .net based web applications (taking advantage of WIF framework), our ADFS act as IDP. Finally when user ends up on web application, we receive all transformed claims from client IDPs.
One of our client IDP uses SAML protocol, which is nicely converted to WIF claims by ADFS and web application can read these claims. But we have new requirement, where we will also need to read untouched SAML Protocol response which is http-posted to ADFS by client IDP during SSO handshake. During this HTTP POST on ADFS, we receive SAMLResponse and RelayState as 2 different parameters. Now this message is converted to WIF based params (wa, wresult, wctx) by ADFS and posted to our web applications.
Our web application acting as relying party on ADFS 3.0 is configured with WS-Federation Passive Endpoints. There is possibility of adding additional SAML Assertion Consumer. But I am not sure how I can mix and match multiple endpoints?
Any idea how I will get SAMLResponse parameter which was originally posted on ADFS. Is it achievable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The SAMLResponse is sent to only one EndPoint. Adding an EndPoint will not give you an extra copy.

ADFS does not have a "span" port (outgoing copy for Log). A reverse proxy/loadbalancer often has a "copy" port feature. But if the SAML token is encrypted then you still need the private key of the ADFS Decryption cert.

A lot of work.

Comment: On one of the other part you mentioned about adding custom http handler or http module on ADFS to receive SAMLResponse param. How do I proceed with that? I do not wish to decrypt it. All I need to do is pass it along to RP and use it further to call clients secured webservices. All this and without causing any issues to other IDPs integrations. Thanks.

Comment: The path of HttpHandlers and HttpModules is over. ADFS on S2012R2 and later does not allow that any longer. Besides that you would have to implement the SAML2 protocol. That is way too much work. Just let ADFS pass it to SAML2 protocol Applications. Or I must have misunderstood your question.

Comment: we have 2 claims provider and single relying party (.net web app). Thinktecture IDP and client's SAML based IDP. ADFS 3.0 for federation. RP is configured with WS-Fed Passive Endpoint. All is working well as expected. With new requirement, I need actual SAMLResponse, posted on ADFS by client's SAML IDP. Any suggestions, how I can achieve it? Unfortunately, I did not understand your previous suggestion about "Just let ADFS pass it to SAML2 protocol Applications". How do I do this? Will this have any adverse effect on Thinktecture IDP? Do my RP receive same set of claims after making changes?

Comment: "Just let ADFS pass": I meant use a SAMLP Relying party, not WS-Fed. I was assuming that the RP was SAMLP. Incorrect assumption. I honestly think that it is not possible to pass the SAMLResponse.